# javascript create content

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a text area (from which I take a number) and button to submit the value, and I'm trying to add content to a paragraph that is generated by this loop:

```
var countNum = document.getElementById(num).value;
var entNum = parseInt(countNum);

for(i=1;i<=entNum;i++){
    if(i%3!==0 && i%7!==0){
       document.write(i + "<br>");
    }
}
```

now when i use `document.write` of course the whole previous content is overwritten, but I want to have a paragraph under the button, that receives the generated numbers from the loop and them. What's the right way to do it ?

Comment: generate your html in a variable. and then insert it into your paragraphs

Comment: Go and read [a DOM tutorial](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have a container below your button, where you'll put your stuff in:

```
<button [...] />
<div id="myContainer"></div>
```

Then you can fill the container by calling

```
var myContainer = document.getElementById("myContainer");
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode("YourNumberOrTextHere"));
myContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
```

You'll find out the rest! ;)

---

EDIT:
Following your comment, the following addition:

To remove an element, you'll need a reference to it.

**By ID:**

```
//Create element and give it a unique ID
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.id = "element1";
//Now you can get it like this
var paragraph = document.getElementById("element1");
```

**By TagName:**

```
//Request all elements with a certain tag name
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
//or only those of our container:
var paragraphs = document.getElementById("myContainer").getElementsByTagName("p");
//Now you can mess with all of them like this:
var paragraph = paragraphs[0]
```

**By Reference:**

```
//Just reuse the variable you used when you created your element
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
//use paragraph
```

**More to find out:**

```
;)
```

**NOW: Removing it:**

You have to tell the parentContainer that it should remove a child element. Fortunately, each element saves a reference to its parent:

```
paragraph.parentElement.removeChild(paragraph);
```

Comment: Yes that's the best approach IMO. [Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/5SMuQ/) using this concept.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly! Now I'll try to figure out how to remove the previous content and add new in its place.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
var countNum = document.getElementById(num).value;
var entNum = parseInt(countNum);
var html = ''

for(i=1;i<=entNum;i++){
    if(i%3!==0 && i%7!==0){
       html += i + "<br>";
    }
}
```

and then insert the html anywhere you need it...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the innerHTML of a container element for eg.

```
<button>Click Me</button>
<div id="container"></div>

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = content;
```

The other option is to construct the paragraph using the DOM API